# Remove space between string and variable when priting

Tags: python

First time stackoverflow user. My code:

```
print("charge  :",currency,("%.2f" % charge))
```

I am trying to print:

> charge  : $20.00

However, with the current code it comes out with a space between $ and the variable output. Like this:

> charge  : $ 20.00

Is there any suggestion on how to resolve this? Apologies if this has already been answered.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to use an f-string:

```
print(f"charge : {currency}{charge:.2f}")
```

(Other options include using `sep=''` to remove the spaces, or using `+` to concatenate the strings yourself, but this makes for code that's harder to read IMO.)

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` function has an argument that allows you to change the separator of the various elements you print. It is set to a space by default, `sep=' '`, but it can be anything. So, if you want to remove the space, you can add this this:

```
print("charge :", currency, ("%.2f" % charge), sep='')
```